# Headers and Getters in HttpServletRequest

Tags: java, servlets

I am working with HttpServletRequest, and I must output all headers and information from that object.

for the headers I am using `getHeadersNames()`

```
Enumeration<String> headerEnums = servletRequest.getHeaderNames();
while (headerEnums.hasMoreElements()) {  
    String elementName = headerEnums.nextElement();
    String elementValue = servletRequest.getHeader(elementName);
    sb.append("Header.").append(elementName).append("=").append(elementValue).append(", ");
}
```

and afterwards I am retrieving all parameters using getters, for example:

```
sb.append("getAuthType").append("=").append(servletRequest.getAuthType());
```

I am getting duplicate arguments for example `Header.content-type` and `ContentType` from `getContentType()`

my questions:

1. There is a nice way to output all `servletRequest` parameters without iterate over `headers`, `attributes` and getters? like toString()?
2. How can i avoid retrieving duplicate arguments without having a temporal set?
3. Is it possible to have an header inside Headers where its getter is empty? for example: `content-type` exist in Headers but `getContentType()` is null?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterMap() will return all request parameters as a Map.

Comment: @ramp I'm pretty sure that OP wants a method that returns everything - query params,  headers, etc.

Comment: @SvetlinZarev, you are right, because the post and the code is all about headers. I just responded to the question literally :)

Comment: @ramp thank you, but I looked for a method that returns everything, I thought it was clear from the title and explanation, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer is in the context of Apache Tomcat (8.5).

> Is it possible to have an header inside Headers where its getter is empty? for example: content-type exist in Headers but `getContentType()` is `null`?

It's not possible, unless there is a bug. Those methods query the same internal data structure that contains the headers.

> How can i avoid retrieving duplicate arguments without having a temporal set?

You are querying the same data structure twice - so it's pretty simple - do not ask twice for the same thing. Either use the headers, or use the methods from HttpServletRequest. The only difference is, that when using the methods, you'll get a default value (like -1, if the Content-Length is unknown), while you'll get NULL if you ask for a missing header.

> There is a nice way to output all ServletRequest parameters without iterate over headers, attributes and getters? like toString()

At least I'm not aware of such standard method.